# Equivalencias de C++ en Python: fread y struct con constructor

Tags: python, c++, fread

## Introduccion

Por motivos de aprendizaje, estoy adaptando el codigo de este [repositorio](https://github.com/srmeier/N3Terrain) a Python.
He iniciado por el archivo `Main.cpp` en la cual inicia como:

```
// file Main.cpp
FILE* fpMap = fopen("karus_start.gtd", "rb");
if (fpMap == NULL) {
    printf("ER: File not found!\n\n");
    system("pause");
    return -1;
}
```

cuyo equivalente en python es sencillo:

```
import os
import struct

PATCH_TILE_SIZE = 8
FLT_MIN = 1.175494351e-38

def open_ko_file(name):
    with open(name, 'rb') as fname:
        ko_file = fname.read()

     print('file opened correctly!')
    return ko_file

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fpMap = open_ko_file('karus_start.gtd')

    if fpMap == None:
        print('Error: File not found!')
        os.system('exit')
```

## Problema

Mi duda inicia al intentar leer el contenido de `fpMap` que corresponde a una estructura llamada `_N3MapData`. Para reproducir el problema y ver el avance que he realizado muestro como aborde una seccion de codigo similar a la que me da problemas

La forma en que aborde una seccion donde se leen los primeros 4 bytes del archivo cargado desde C++ es la siguietne :

```
// file Main.cpp : get the size of the map
int m_ti_MapSize = 0;
fread(&m_ti_MapSize, sizeof(int), 1, fpMap);
printf("DB: m_ti_MapSize = %d\n\n", m_ti_MapSize);
```

cuya salida es:

`DB: m_ti_MapSize = 513`

En Python pude interpretar esto de la siguiente manera:

```
m_ti_MapSize = struct.unpack("i", fpMap[:4])[0] 
print(f'DB: m_ti_MapSize = {m_ti_MapSize}')
```

donde obtengo la misma salida:

`DB: m_ti_MapSize = 513`

##### La estructura en C++ que se me complica es:

```
struct _N3MapData {
    float fHeight;
    unsigned int bIsTileFull : 1;
    unsigned int Tex1Dir : 5;
    unsigned int Tex2Dir : 5;
    unsigned int Tex1Idx : 10;
    unsigned int Tex2Idx : 10;

    _N3MapData(void) {
        bIsTileFull = true;
        fHeight = FLT_MIN;
        Tex1Idx = 1023;
        Tex1Dir = 0;
        Tex2Idx = 1023;
        Tex2Dir = 0;
    }
};
```

##### La lectura en C++ que se me complica es:

```
// NOTE: read in the mapdata
_N3MapData* m_pMapData = new _N3MapData[m_ti_MapSize*m_ti_MapSize]; 
printf("size of _N3MapData  = %u\n", sizeof(_N3MapData)); //retorna 8
fread(m_pMapData, sizeof(_N3MapData), m_ti_MapSize*m_ti_MapSize, fpMap); // Que hace esto?
printf("DB: m_pMapData[0] = {\n");
printf("DB:     fHeight     = %f\n", m_pMapData[0].fHeight);
printf("DB:     bIsTileFull = %d\n", m_pMapData[0].bIsTileFull);
printf("DB:     Tex1Dir     = %d\n", m_pMapData[0].Tex1Dir);
printf("DB:     Tex2Dir     = %d\n", m_pMapData[0].Tex2Dir);
printf("DB:     Tex1Idx     = %d\n", m_pMapData[0].Tex1Idx);
printf("DB:     Tex2Idx     = %d\n", m_pMapData[0].Tex2Idx);
printf("DB: }\n\n");
```

la salida de estos ultimos `printf` son:

```
size of _N3MapData  = 8
DB: m_pMapData[0] = {
DB:     fHeight     = 150.433365
DB:     bIsTileFull = 1
DB:     Tex1Dir     = 0
DB:     Tex2Dir     = 0
DB:     Tex1Idx     = 431
DB:     Tex2Idx     = 1023
DB: }
```

La estructura `_N3MapData` se "llama" o "construye" internamente con valores distintos, y a diferencia de Python no veo que reciba algun parametro, ademas me parece que esta creando un array de `m_ti_MapSize*m_ti_MapSize` elementos que son instancias de `_N3MapData`. Luego este "array" esta siendo llenado con la instruccion `fread` y se imprimen los valores del primer elemento del array.

Como entiendo el funcionamiento de la funcion de C++ `fread` es de la siguiente forma:

`fread(donde guardar, cantidad de bytes de cada objeto, cantidad de objetos, archivo binario)`
y entiendo que esta funcion lee `cantidad de bytes de cada objeto`*`cantidad de objetos` bytes de `archivo binario` (del 4to byte en adelante porque ya ha leido los primeros 4), asi que en mi implementacion tengo en esencia:

```
class _N3MapData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bIsTileFull = True
        self.fHeight = FLT_MIN
        self.Tex1Idx = 1023
        self.Tex1Dir = 0
        self.Tex2Idx = 1023
        self.Tex2Dir = 0

[
 struct.unpack("q", fpMap[4:4+8]),  # porque _N3MapData ocupa 8 bytes
 struct.unpack("q", fpMap[4+8:4+8+8]), # para los siguientes 8 bytes
 struct.unpack("q", fpMap[4+8+8:4+8+8+8]), # para los siguientes 8 bytes
 ...
] #pero aun falta pasarlos por la clase, lo cual no entiendo como lo hace el archivo original en C++
```

### Pregunta:

Es correcta la manera que muestro de leer los bytes (a partir del 4to byte) y llevarlos a una clase en python? (Es decir, llevarlos en bloques de 8 en 8 porque entiendo que eso es lo que hace en esencia la funcion de C++ `fread`)

La referencia de lectura de `struct.unpack("q", ..` la obtuve de [aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters), por lo que puede ser cualquier formato de tamaño 8.

nota: el archivo leido se encuentra en el repositorio o en este [link](https://github.com/srmeier/N3Terrain/blob/master/N3Terrain/karus_start.gtd)
La referencia de este codigo tambien se encuentra "explicada"  [aqui](https://stephenmeier.net/2017/02/27/knight-online-terrain-gtd-format-for-1299/)

Comment: Buen día, hay varias preguntas en una sola publicación, te recomiendo repasar [ask].

Answer (score 1):

La pregunta es demasiado larga y tiene demasiados detalles como para poder responder a cada uno de ellos. Daría lugar a una respuesta igualmente larguísima y de poca utilidad para el público general. Por tanto opto mejor por darte algunos conceptos generales y consejos para que tú mismo puedas deducir cómo continuar. Aún así me ha quedado una respuesta muy larga.

### El problema

El archivo que estás intentando leer tiene una cierta estructura "rígida" en términos de qué datos se esperan, en qué orden, y de qué tamaño es cada dato. La estructura de ese fichero parece haber sido deducida por "ingniería inversa" por lo que algunos de sus contenidos, aunque se sabe dónde están y cuánto ocupan, no se sabe para qué sirven. Por ejemplo, se sabe que los primeros 4 bytes del fichero codifican un entero. De forma análoga el fichero contiene otras ciertas estructuras de datos de tamaño fijo.

Este tipo de ficheros son fáciles de leer en C, puesto que C también tiene variables de tamaño fijo (un `int` son 4 bytes, un `long int` son 8, etc). Además, es más que probable que el fichero que intentas leer haya sido generado desde C, volcando directamente ciertas estructuras, por lo que leerlo de nuevo desde C es la opción más natural, basta cargar de nuevo las mismas estructuras en el mismo orden en que fueron escritas.

Leer los datos binarios desde Python no es problema. Se puede abrir el fichero en modo "b" y leer de ahí los bytes. El problema viene al tratar de interpretar esos bytes como datos.

### El módulo `struct` en Python

Este módulo está justamente para ayudar con este tipo de lecturas y escrituras. Permite decodificar como entero o como float ciertas secuencias de bytes encontradas en el fichero. Está pensado básicamente para poder recuperar en Python datos escritos desde C.

Pero está pensado para trabajar con **datos no estructurados**, es decir, básicamente enteros, floats, strings y char. Nada más. No está pensado para trabajar con listas, clases, diccionarios y el resto de tipos típicos de Python.

La conversión a éstos debe hacerse ya manualmente.

### Un ejemplo

No voy a usar el formato de tu fichero, que es demasiado complejo para la respuesta que pretendo dar. Plantearé un ejemplo más sencillo y te dejo a ti que extrapoles a tu caso (si te aparecen nuevas dudas, más concretas, puedes plantear nuevas preguntas).

Imagina que en C has volcado una estructura como esta:

```
struct MiEstructura {
    float altura;
    int   indice;
    float x, y;
}
```

Para sabe a cuántos bytes dará lugar al ser volcado a fichero necesitas conocer los tamaños de los tipos en C. Si no los conoces puedes escribir un pequeño programa C que imprima `sizeof(float)`, `sizeof(int)`. Verás que sale 4. Por tanto la estructura anterior ocupará 16 bytes de los cuales los 4 primeros corresponden al campo `altura`, los 4 siguientes al campo `indice`, los 4 siguientes al campo `x` y los 4 siguientes al campo `y`.

Además necesitamos saber si el fichero guarda esa información en formato *big endian* o en formato *little endian* (es decir, un campo de 4 bytes como `altura` ¿en qué orden guarda sus bytes? ¿Es el primer byte el que corresponde a los bits más significativos de la variable `altura`, o es el que corresponde a los bits menos significativos?

Supongamos que es *little endian* (es una suposición razonable si el fichero fue volcado desde una arquitectura Intel, pero en realidad es un dato que deberíamos conocer a priori, pues es una decisión del creador del formato del archivo).

Para recuperar esa información en Python harías por tanto:

```
altura, indice, x, y = struct.unpack("<f<i<f<f", array_bytes)
```

donde `array_bytes` sería un array con 16 bytes (la estructura de datos leida del fichero), y `"<f<i<f<f"` es la cadena de formato que le dice a `unpack()` cómo interpretarlos (los `<` son para indicar la *endianity* y las letras `f` o `i` para indicar que el dato es de tipo float o entero, python ya sabe cuántos bytes leer para cada caso).

`upack()` retorna una tupla cuyos elementos son los datos ya "decodificados" y por tanto en forma de variables python. Las variables python no ocupan lo mismo que las variables C, y por eso no puedes leer directamente una estructura de disco y guardarla en una clase. Pero ahora que ya hemos leido los valores, nada nos impide usarlos para instanciar la clase apropiada, por ejemplo así:

```
data = MiEstructuraPython(altura, indice, x, y)
```

suponiendo que `MiEstructuraPython` es una clase previamente declarada tal que así:

```
class MiEstructuraPython:
   def __init__(self, altura, indice, x, y):
       self.altura = altura
       self.indice = indice
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
```

Este tipo de clases en Python cuya única misión es guardar datos pero que no van a implementar métodos para manipularlos, son lo más parecido a una estructura del C. Una vez has inicializado `data` como antes se mostró, puedes acceder a `data.indice`, `data.x`, etc...

Recientes versiones de python incorporan el concepto de *dataclass* que es precisamente para esto, clases que simplemente almacenan datos. En este caso puedes declararlo de forma más sencilla:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MiEstructuraPython:
   altura: float
   indice: int
   x: float
   y: float
```

y python se ocupará de escribir por tí el constructor `__init__()` y un montón de métodos más de utilidad para imprimir objetos de este tipo (`print(data)`) y que se vea bonito, para poder comparar un objeto de este tipo con otro y así poder ordenarlos (se compararían por su primer atributo, altura, y en caso de empate por el siguiente, etc)

### Campos de bits

C admite también declarar elementos de una estructura con un tamaño **en bits**. Eso es lo que tienes aqui por ejemplo:

```
struct _N3MapData {
    float fHeight;
    unsigned int bIsTileFull : 1;
    unsigned int Tex1Dir : 5;
    unsigned int Tex2Dir : 5;
    unsigned int Tex1Idx : 10;
    unsigned int Tex2Idx : 10;
    ...
```

Salvo el primer campo que es `float`, los siguientes son campos de bits. El primero ocupa 1 bit, los dos siguientes 5 bits cada uno y los dos siguientes 10 bits cada uno. Echando cuentas eso hacen 31 bits. 31 bits caben en 4 bytes, por lo que todos esos campos realmente se van a codificar en solo 4 bytes (que es el tamaño de un `unsigned int`)

Decodificar esto con Python es más complicado. Para empezar debes desempaquetar todos esos campos como un solo dato, de tipo `unsigned int`, esto sería algo así:

```
fHeight, bitField = struct.unpack("<f<I", byte_array)
```

Donde `<I` indica "unsigned int en orden little endian", y donde `byte_array` sería un array de 8 bytes (los 4 primeros serían el float y los 4 siguientes el campo de bits).

Pero para después desempaquetar el campo de bits ya tendrás que echar mano de operaciones *bitwise* (a nivel de bits). Así por ejemplo `(bitField >> 31) & 1` se quedaría con el primer bit del campo, que es lo que en la estructura C habíamos llamado `bIsTileFull`. Además, tal como se está usando en C parece que se trate de un booleano, por lo que en Python sería más correcto guardarlo como `True` o `False` y no como 1 ó 0, por lo que se podría hacer:

```
bIsTileFull = (bitField & 0x80000000) != 0
```

Otro ejemplo para terminar. El campo `unsigned int Tex1Dir : 5;` del C, serían los 5 siguientes bits de `bitField` y podrías obtenerlos así:

```
Tex1Dir = (bitField >> 26) & 0b11111
```

Esto comienza por desplazar hacia la derecha los bits de `bitFields` 26 unidades, para que los 5 bits que interesan queden abajo del todo, y luego hace una máscara con un valor binario de 5 unos, para eliminar los restantes bits que pudiera haber por encima. La siguiente figura aclara la idea

[image: Figura]

Y de forma análoga deberías tratar el resto de los campos del campo de bits.

### Conclusión

Como ves, la "traducción" de estructuras de datos C a Python no es tan simple como leerlo de un fichero (ni siquiera con la ayuda de `struct.unpack()`. Hay partes que tendrás que hacer manualmente.

La biblioteca [bitstruct](https://bitstruct.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) puede ser de ayuda para manejar los campos de tipo bitfield, pues te proporciona una función similar a `struct.unpack()` para "desempaquetar" grupos de bits individuales, si la entrada es una cadena de bytes.

Comment: Valiosa respuesta para una pregunta que no merece ser respondida.

Comment: @CandidMoe Bueno, mis respuestas casi nunca van dirigidas a quien preguntó, sino a otros que puedan tener un problema similar. O también, en muchos casos, son respuestas para mi yo futuro, que mi memoria va en declive :-)

Comment: Incluso si no cierran la pregunta es una respuesta pérdida, pues el largo de la pregunta la hace ilegible. Si nadie lee la pregunta, nadie verá la respuesta. Lo mejor sería que hicieras una pregunta-respuesta que ilustre mejor el punto.

Comment: @CandidMoe Estoy de acuerdo en parte. Depende de cómo se busque la pregunta. Si alguien entra en SOes y busca su duda, será difícil que dé con esta pregunta. Pero si usa google para buscar cosas como "python, struct, bitfield" etc, es posible que le lleve a esta respuesta. De todas formas me parece buena idea tu sugerencia y lo haré si la pregunta termina cerrada.